# Terraform AWS The security group does not exist when it does exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

I have a security group with name "basic connectivity" on my AWS.

I wrote a Terraform script to create an AWS instance but it states that the Security group does not exists when it actually does exist in the same Default VPC and region.

The part where it fails is here:

```
resource "aws_default_vpc" "default" {

  tags = {
    Name = "Default VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_olympus" {
  vpc_id            = aws_default_vpc.default.id
  cidr_block        = "172.31.150.0/24"
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "nint_olympus" {

  subnet_id   = aws_subnet.subnet_olympus.id
  private_ips = ["172.31.150.100"]

  security_groups = ["sg-09ef716b3eb847691"]

}
```

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. The only reason it could fail is because `sg-09ef716b3eb847691` is wrong. So you have to double check it.

Comment: It's literally identical

Comment: You verified region and VPC. What about account? Maybe your TF executes for different account that you think?

Comment: Same account, same region, same VPC. When i launch other instances it works, as long as i don't include the security group. The moment i include security group, it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try passing those sg ids via a data source
[Datasource SG](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/security_groups)

Answer (score 0):

You can try pointing to the Security Group using the syntax below:

security_groups = [ "${aws_security_group.YOUR-SECURITY-GROUP-NAME.name}" ]
or
security_groups = [ "${aws_security_group.YOUR-SECURITY-GROUP-NAME.id}" ]